# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: southern latitude exceeds northern latitude (23.029011581089936 > 23.0060917)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm working on Google Maps, I found a strange error which I never came across before: Here are the details.

I am trying to put two markers in the boundary using,

`latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(mDestination, mOrigin);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(mDestination).include(mOrigin);`

I get following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: southern latitude exceeds northern latitude (23.029011581089936 > 23.0060917)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source:38)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.cmrlabs.tracker.MainActivity.drawRoute(MainActivity.java:324)
    at com.cmrlabs.tracker.MainActivity.access$500(MainActivity.java:73)
    at com.cmrlabs.tracker.MainActivity$2.onMapClick(MainActivity.java:410)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzy.onMapClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzak.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
    at cj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831068@19.8.31 (100700-0):14)
```

I have no clue how to fix this, any suggestions?

Thank you in advance..!

Comment: HuaweiMaps throw the same exception if `getActivity().isFinishing()` returns true.
The stacktrace was like this: `2020-05-18 12:17:06.942 15722-15722/me.com.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.com.myApp, PID: 15722
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: southern latitude >= northern latitude
        at com.huawei.hms.common.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.<init>(LatLngBounds.java:57)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(LatLngBounds.java:253)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [LatLngBounds constructor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#LatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) takes two parameters: the southwest and northeast corner. That isn't what you have - you have two points, so you shouldn't be using that constructor. Instead, use the `Builder` and call `build()` on it in the end to construct the `LatLngBounds` object:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(mDestination).include(mOrigin);
latLngBounds = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

me helped answer ianhanniballake.
If anyone needed on Kotlin behold:

```
val bilder = LatLngBounds.builder()
bilder.include(TripMetrFragment.latLngFinish).include(TripMetrFragment.latLngStart)
val latLngBounds = bilder.build()
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 0))
```